# Regex php for get the ID Number

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I Create the Shortcode for soundcloud clips within my wordpres theme i use the code within my wordpress posts by this way `[soundcloud id="146266424"][/soundclou]`. when the `146266424` it is the soundcloud clip ID. I want create regular php expression by using `preg_match_all` function to match the ID number. by this way

```
$pattern = "//";
$subject = get_the_content();
if ( preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches) ) {
    echo $matches;
}
```

how i can create `pattern` regex code until when i `echo $matches` directly show me the `146266424` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your php code would be,

```
$pattern = '~soundcloud\s*id="\K[^"]*~';
$subject = get_the_content();
if ( preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches) ) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lV0xO6/1)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the tags are really always exactly in this format, that should do the job:

```
$pattern = "/\[soundcloud id=\"(\d+)\"\]/";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$regex = '~\[soundcloud id="\K\d+~';
$count = preg_match_all($regex, $yourstring, $matches);
if($count) print_r($matches[0]);
```

See the matches in [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/yB5sQ0/2).

**Explanation**

- `\[soundcloud id="` matches literal chars
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns
- `\d+` matches one or more digits
- `$matches[0]` contains the ids

Comment: than you my brother it is work perfectly with me